# Is a TypeScript interface the same as a C struct?

Tags: typescript

As far as I understand, TypeScript interfaces can have only properties, and not methods. Coming from C++, this makes them look more like Plain C structs than C++ interfaces, which usually have methods without implementation and no data members.

Is it correct to consider TypeScript interfaces to be like old-style data structures? The only difference that I see is that the members themselves can be "objects" which have methods of their own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not true to say they can't have methods.

They can define methods to be implemented by any class implementing the interface in much the same way as interfaces from other languages, e.g.:

```
export interface IStudent {
  Name: string;
  IsEnrolled: boolean;
  Enroll();
}

export class Student implements IStudent {
  Name: string;
  IsEnrolled: boolean;
  Enroll() {
    this.IsEnrolled = true;
  }
}
```